# Android moving edit text automitcally

Tags: android

I have three EditText views named `edittext_one` ,`edittext_two` and `edittext_three`. I have put these views in a ScrollView. These EditTexts are clearly visible on the screen until my keyboard is not open. Now, I click on `edittext_one`, which is at the top, and my keyboard appears. Then, it hides my `edittext_two` and `edittext_three`. I want to go `edittext_two` just little bit up when I am typing in `edittext_one` so that user can see `edittext_two`. Same is happen with `edittext_three`. When user click on `edittext_two`, `edittext_three` slightly move up so user can see it.
I have lots of EditText in a scrollView, but I have just explained here three.
Please don't suggest me to use **adjust pan and adjust resize** because it never solves my problem.

Here is the link I used for iPhone
[Sliding UITextFields around to avoid the keyboard](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html) but how do I do this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a click listener on edittext_one that does this:

```
int top = edittext_two.getTop();
scrollView.scrollTo(0,top);
```

Comment: I tried with it but its not working. its just pushing the whole view up i mean edittext_two get at the top and edittext_one in no more visible.